# Label text getting mixed up

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The tableView displayed below contains `label`. They are added as `subView` for each cell.

When I run my program for the first time, the cells that appear on the screen have the correct text. But when I scroll the table, the text in the labels begin to get mixed up. From what I understand the label of one cell is overlaid on top of another when the cell is created. This has been shown in the latter two screenshots. After each scroll, the different cells are overlaid on top of the other. (So there is no fixed pattern.) I tried to understand the problem by observing which cell which were going out of the screen and the ones which were entering. I tried to correlate this information with the labels on the cells, but I am not able to understand.

I request you to kindly help me understand the cause for this discrepancy.

Thanks you!

[image]

The relevant section of my code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSLog(@"s = %d, r = %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            [cell addSubview:classA];
            break;

            case 1:
            [cell addSubview:classB];
            break;

        case 2:
            [cell addSubview:classC];
            break;

        case 3:
            [cell addSubview:classD];
            break;

        case 4:
            [cell addSubview:classE];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            [cell addSubview:classF];
            break;

        case 1:
            [cell addSubview:classG];
            break;

        case 2:
            [cell addSubview:classH];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            [cell addSubview:classI];
            break;

        case 1:
            [cell addSubview:classJ];
            break;

        case 2:
            [cell addSubview:classK];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to reuse the cells. So when you are scrolling, the cells which are going out of visible area are getting reused for the current visible cells.

Since you have already added labels like `classB` etc.. in these cells and not removed after that, and after that when you are adding labels such as `classI` etc.. on the same reused cells, it is getting drawn on top of this label. Since these labels have background color set as clear color, it will show the label which was drawn behind it also and hence giving an overlapping feeling.

As per the screenshot, all the cells are looking identical and you can definitely reuse the cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. So why dont you change your logic of creating the label outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and instead just use it as `cell.TextLabel.text = @"Class B";` etc.. in the corresponding if conditions inside this method?

Your code will look like,

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            cell.textLabel = [self createLabelForRow:indexPath.row section:indexPath.section];
//or if it is jut a simple label, you can just set font and other properties in cell.textLabel directly
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class A";
            break;
```

**Update:** Here is a not-so-good fix for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` reuse in case all cells are static. But this is not a recommended approach.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellForRow%dSection%d",indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
   { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

  //or try this

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
  if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
```

**Update2:** So if you are facing issues with above try this. Use my first approach and do the following.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            cell.textLabel = [self createLabelForRow:indexPath.row section:indexPath.section];

            // or do the following,

            [self removeAllTextFieldsFromCell:cell];
            UITextField *aTextField = [self createTextFieldForRow:indexPath.row section:indexPath.section];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:aTextField];
         }
```

In `removeAllTextFieldsFromCell:` method use the R.A's suggestion.

For eg:-

```
- (void)removeAllTextFieldsFromCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {

    for (UITextField *textField in cell.contentViews.subViews) {
        [textField removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Or just use,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSLog(@"s = %d, r = %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

    //if it is all textfields in the cell, it will look like,
    [self removeAllTextFieldsFromCell:cell];
    UITextField *aTextField = [self createTextFieldForRow:indexPath.row section:indexPath.section];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aTextField];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. `cell.textLabel.text` is certainly an option and I have explored it.  However, I run to similar problems if I use `textFields`. So I am really eager to solve this problem.

Comment: what can be the alternative to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

Comment: @Rut, What is the problem you have faced with textfields? In that case you might need to have a logic to remove all previously added subviews from cell before adding a new label. Anyways check my update. That will fix your issue.

Comment: I wanted to change the `placeHolder` of the textField depending on the selection made on the above screen. Imagine there are more `textFields` than the ones that can be accommodated on the screen, I have to scroll down to see others. But when I scroll up, I see the text in the fields starts interefering with the newly inserted `placeHolder`.

Comment: @Rut, If you are using static cells, then you can just pass nil as the reuse identifier. That will definitely fix this issue. Try it and let me know. Check my answer now.

Comment: @ACB Setting static cells are not recommended I think. he may have large number of cells and it may use of large amount of memory and performance issue may get created.

Comment: @ACB: I ran the program with the modification that you have suggested. It is much better this time. However, I dont see the textLabel appear in the second and third last cells. So I deleted the app from the phone and did clean build. But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @R.A, check his comment, "the cells are static. There are 11 cells, each containing unique text. – Rut 11 mins ago"

Comment: @Rut, Which one did you try? passing nil or setting cellidentifier as unique?

Comment: oh.. i just realized that you made an edit. I tried the one with `nil`.

Comment: @ACB: From Rut's comments to my answer (almost simultaneously posted as yours :-) it seems to me that your first suggestion (creating a text label once ...) is the best solution in this case.

Comment: @MartinR, you are correct, That is what I always prefer. I added the edit, since he didnt want to follow that approach.

Comment: @MartinR: It is certainly a great solution. But I run into similar problem with textField placeHolder. So my goal is to understand the problem and the best solution that can work in many scenarios.

Comment: @ACB martin is correct. If you tell him to use static cells, then he will use the same thing for his all future projects. Give him a better solution is correct way. i think so.

Comment: guys.. pls give me a min. I just want to understand your suggestions correctly

Comment: @Rut: Perhaps you should update your question with the new code, so that we can see what the "similar problem with textField placeHolder" might be.

Comment: @Rut, I have updated my answer. Sorry for all the confusions.

Comment: @ACB: no issues. I too found the reason why I was not seeing the third and second last rows. It was because I had used `switch (indexPath.section)` instead of `switch (indexPath.row)` for `Category 3`. So now the program works fine when I use cellIdentifier as `nil` or customized. I will just go through the your answer to see what has been changed.

Comment: @Rut, Nice to know that it worked for you. But as Martin and R.A suggested, try to reduce the usage of static cells. If possible create the labels or textfields in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method and try to reuse the cells. That should eventually help you a lot in performance optimization. :)

Comment: I see. I will certainly try it. So if I use dynamic labels, I will have to create labels/textFields or other oobjects programmatically.. right? In one of my previous practice apps, I created the textFields programmatically, but i realized that I had to write a lot of code repeatedly.

Comment: @Rut, For textfields, you might have to create as shown above in my method. For labels, you can use cell.TextLabel property and just change the .text property alone.

Answer (score 3):

Table view cells are *reused*: If you scroll up or down, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` may return a cell that was previously used for a different (now invisible) row.

In that case the cell already contains one of your subviews and you add an additional subview.

Comment: thanks for your response. So if the cell is invisible, it is still there in the memory? I thought it would be deleted? what can be the alternative to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Is the table view static (fixed number of rows/sections) or dynamic? How many different cell types do you have?

Comment: the cells are static. There are 11 cells, each containing unique text.

Comment: @Rut: And is the type of the cells fixed (e.g. section 0/row 0 is always "classA") or does it change?

Comment: It was always remains the same. Each cell contains a label and the text of the label remains the same throughout the program.

Comment: @Rut: But then it seems to me that the first suggestion in ACB's answer is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comment as `textfield`, then you need to `remove the old` `textField` from your cell.
You can add this code before your `if statement for indexPath.section checking`.

```
for (UITextField *textField in cell.contentViews.subViews) {
    [textField removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment R.A. I am having multiple selection of cells. Assuming some cells in the first screen are selected and if I use `removeFromSuperView`, will the selected cells retain the selection when they reappear?

Comment: this is where you need to take care everything. Because iOS wont take care of retain your selection. When user select the multiple cells you need to store it and reselect those cells again when you scroll the tableview. If you dont do that, then you gonna get this same error like messing up of selection of different cells.Just like  in your question

Comment: removeFromSuperView wont affect anything else in your cell expect removing the textField which is useless for your current cell.simply thats all

Comment: @RA: I will try your method too. Right now I am trying ACB's method. But thanks for your input.