# Keeping a track of selected cells

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app, the user changes the fields that appear in a tableView depending on the cells selected by him/her. (FYI... I have permitted multiple cell selection.) Just when the user presses the back button, the program copies the textLabel of the selected cells to the placeholder of the parent viewController.

Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
int tempCount = 0;

for (int section = 0; section < 3; section++)
{
    int rowMax;

    if (section == 0)
        rowMax = 3;

    else if (section == 1)
        rowMax = 5;

    else if(section == 2)
        rowMax = 3;

    for(int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];

        if(selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
            NSLog(@"tempCount = %d", tempCount);
            tempCount++;

            if (tempCount == 1)
                chosenFieldsViewController.field0.placeholder = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

            else if(tempCount == 2)
                chosenFieldsViewController.field1.placeholder = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

            else if(tempCount == 3)
                chosenFieldsViewController.field2.placeholder = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

        }
    }
}
}
```

I realized that after selecting the cells if the tableView is scrolled down, the selected cells do not appear as placeHolder on the parentVC. From my analysis I think that once I scroll down, the cells are deleted from the memory. So despite the fact that the cells are selected, they fail to show up on the parent VC.

If so, why do I see the cells appear selected when I scroll up?

I would be grateful if somebody can suggest how I can keep a track of the selected cells even when the user scrolls.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(selectedCell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark && count<3)
{
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    count ++;
}

else if(selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    count--;
}

}
```

**Edit 2**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellForRow%dSection%d",indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // VERY IMPORTANT

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{        
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class A";
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class B";
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class C";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 1)
{        
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class D";
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class E";
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class F";
            break;

        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class G";
            break;

        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class H";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class I";
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class J";
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Class K";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to do this `chosenFieldsViewController.field0.placeholder = selectedCell.textLabel.text;` as and when user enters the text. Otherwise you have to store this in some form in your class so that while scrolling you wont lose this information.

Comment: @ACB : I had thought of the exact same solution that you have mentioned. But it's slightly tricky. There are three sections and I want the fields to appear in the same order that they have been selected. The code becomes slightly complex if the user deselects a field and selects a fields from another section. To help you visualize, please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460535/label-text-getting-mixed-up . Infact, I am still grateful that you had helped me solve one of the major issues with the app. :-)

Comment: Nice to know that it helped. :) Can you please share some more code. Only way to achieve the above is by storing it as and when user enters text. If you can share some more code, probably we can check how to overcome those complex scenarios you are facing. As per my understanding as and when user is entering something you need to store it in array or so and remove it if user deselects the cell. Then add when user select next one. This array will always be in the order user selected things.

Comment: @ACB: I have just inserted another method in my question. Apart from this, do you also want to see cellForIndexPathForRow?

Comment: Yes, That also would help anyone who is looking into this question.

Comment: Please take a look at it now..

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works the way you wanted. If not, please let me know the issue you are facing with this.

Comment: great! thanks! :-) pls give me a few mins to modify and run the code.

Comment: If the above cellForRowAtIndexPath is your actual code, I would suggest you to store those texts in array and use it as cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; you dont need to use these many if else conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a dictionary as,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *selectedTextListDict;
```

In viewDidLoad,

```
NSMutableDictionary *selectedTextListDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then change these methods as,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(selectedCell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark && count < 3)
    {
        NSString *rowKeyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        NSString *sectionKeyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];

        NSMutableDictionary *row = [self.selectedTextListDict valueForKey:sectionKeyString];
        if (!row) {
            row = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
        [row setObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text forKey:rowKeyString];
        [self.selectedTextListDict setObject:row forKey:sectionKeyString];

        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        count ++;
    }

    else if(selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {

        NSString *rowKeyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        NSString *sectionKeyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];

        NSMutableDictionary *row = [self.selectedTextListDict valueForKey:sectionKeyString];
        [row removeObjectForKey:rowKeyString];

        if ([[row allKeys] count] == 0) {
            [self.selectedTextListDict removeObjectForKey:sectionKeyString];
        } else {
            [self.selectedTextListDict setObject:row forKey:sectionKeyString];
        }

        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        count--;
    }
}


- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    NSArray *selectedTextSectionKeysList = [self.selectedTextListDict allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedSelectedTextSectionKeysList = [selectedTextSectionKeysList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(intValue)];
    int tempCount = 0;

    for (NSString *sectionString in sortedSelectedTextSectionKeysList) {

        NSMutableDictionary *rowDict = [self.selectedTextListDict valueForKey:sectionString];

        if (rowDict) {

            NSArray *selectedTextRowKeysList = [rowDict allKeys];
            NSArray *sortedSelectedTextRowKeysList = [selectedTextRowKeysList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(intValue)];

            for (NSString *rowString in sortedSelectedTextRowKeysList) {

                tempCount++;

                if (tempCount == 1)
                    chosenFieldsViewController.field0.placeholder = [rowDict valueForKey:rowString];

                else if(tempCount == 2)
                    chosenFieldsViewController.field1.placeholder = [rowDict valueForKey:rowString];

                else if(tempCount == 3)
                    chosenFieldsViewController.field2.placeholder = [rowDict valueForKey:rowString];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoToModifyFieldsViewController"])
    {
        ModifyFieldsViewController *modifyFieldsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        modifyFieldsViewController.chosenFieldsViewController = self;

        field0.placeholder = @"";
        field1.placeholder = @"";
        field2.placeholder = @"";

        if(self.selectedTextListDict)
            self.selectedTextListDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Declare a dictionary in `ChosenFieldsViewController`: as,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *selectedTextListDict;
```

In viewDidLoad,

```
selectedTextListDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Therefore, rather using `self.selectedTextListDict`, use: `chosenFieldsViewController.selectedTextListDict` in `ModifyFieldsViewController`.

Comment: I like you approach. But we aren't there yet. :( I shifted the declaration of selectedTextList to `ChosenFieldsViewController` (parentVC) and replaced them `self.` with chosenFieldsViewController (object of the type: `ChosenFieldsViewController` declared in `ModifyFieldsViewController`). The program works fine if I select three fields in one shot. If I try to modify the fields the next time, I am not able to do so. So I modified the code in `prepareForSegue`. If you don't mind, can I edit your answer to show what I changed?

Comment: Yes, you can edit and add it as an update. I will accept it. Good to know that it worked, because I typed the whole code without using Xcode and hence I was expecting some obvious bugs and logical mistakes Thanks for accepting.

Comment: thanks! btw.. I found one bug. Let me go over it before I edit your answer. The order in which the fields appear is critical to me. However, if the user selects the cells randomly, the fields appear in the order in which they have been selected. So I am trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I thought your question was to get it that way. i.e, in the order in which user selected rather than the in the order of cells. So is it a different case? I can check for an alternate solution.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I should have emphasized that it is important for me to display the fields sorted by section and row. That's the reason why the prog. scans the fields/cells from section 0, row 0 and if it encounters a cell that has been selected, it copies its textLabel to the placeholder. I think we have to use arrays like @Minthos suggestion.

Comment: No, you just need tweak the above code. Let me update it. The other one is a lot of code and it will create performance issue for you finally.

Comment: btw... if I don't mind modifying the setup of the table if it is easier to add a section instead of modifying a row. So each selected field will appear as different section.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19967/discussion-between-acb-and-rut)

Answer (score 0):

-If so, why do I see the cells appear selected when I scroll up?

Because they get created automatically whenever they are about to appear. Every time you scroll up or down, cells get created or reused. When they disappear, they get destroyed or marked for reuse.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So how do we extend the concept to identifying whether the cells are selected or not even though they may not be visibile in the tableView?

Comment: Keep a data structure in your view controller with the necessary metadata. An NSMutableArray of custom objects should do the trick.

Comment: I had tried this also. This makes the code very complicated. I have to write a code corresponding for connection every row and section with an element in the array. For example, if section == 1, row == 4, objectAtIndex:7 should be updated. Therefore, I had to write a long list of if-else ladder. So for a while I flirted with the concept of `plist` and `NSDictionary` also.

Comment: btw.. it would be awesome if there was one line formula connecting the section and row number with the index in the array. I have 3 sections. Section 0 has 3 row, section 1 has 5 rows and section 2 has 3 rows. I derived a formula: `array index = 3*section + row`. This works fine for section 0 and 1, but not for 2. :(

Comment: add "if(section > 1) { index += 2; }" and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I am accepting ACB approach because I could it to be more efficient in terms of coding.